# The 'rest/organizationPageStatistics' endpoint doesn't return all the information

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to migrate to version 202311 and I found out that the Retrieve Lifetime Organization Page Statistics doesn't work as it used to. From this call, I need the information from the pageStatisticsByCountry and pageStatisticsByRegion fields.
From what I understand in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/page-statistics?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http) I can get both fields using the 202311 version, but in postman I don't receive them. The last version I managed to get the fields was 202304.

Is there another call I can make for the 202311 version so that I can get pageStatisticsByCountry and pageStatisticsByRegion ?

[202304](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfxW6.png)
[202311](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Aie.png)

**TL;DR**

**Desired Behaviour**

In the 202311 version of the Retrieve Lifetime Organization Page Statistics endpoint I wish to retrive the pageStatisticsByCountry and pageStatisticsByRegion arrays of objects.

**A specific problem or error**

```
{
  "paging": {
    "start": 0,
    "count": 10,
    "links": []
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "pageStatisticsBySeniority": [
        ...
      ],
      "pageStatisticsByTargetedContent": ...,
      "totalPageStatistics": ...,
      "pageStatisticsByStaffCountRange":...,
      "pageStatisticsByFunction": ...,
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:..."
    }
```

]
}

**The shortest code necessary to produce the problem:**

```
curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A17914697' \
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202311' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
```